# How to precompile a part of Razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there a way to precompile a part of Razor view, which uses tag helpers when the output is always the same?

Every time AnchorTagHelper will transform this code:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="@nameof(HomeController.MyAction)">Link</a>
```

... into something like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/home/myaction">Link</a>
```

The name of controller and action obviously will not change during runtime. So how can I optimize this, without using caching?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want this? Are you having performance issues (then they're probably elsewhere in the code). Don't micro-optimize. It is possible to prerender the pages into static files, but you will need to maintain them (and it will not matter that much in performance). And why don't you want to use caching? And why not hard code it? etc etc.

Comment: I don't have performance issues. Just thought maybe there is a way to remove redundant generation of the same content :)

Comment: Should I not cache these lines which use tag helpers aswell? Is this a bad practice?

Comment: Everything is possible, but (IMHO and I think it's common sense) it doesn't add value. If it's not a performance bottleneck, don't optimize it. It's a waste of time and effort, and makes your code harder to maintain. [Of course you can do it as exercise, but realize that this is not being done (maybe rarely) in real production environments.]

Comment: caching is the way to go here. I don't think there is any kind of partial precompilation. Note that you can cache a part of the content, not the whole razor view/page.

Comment: @KingKing it is actually possible to call the Razor engine and pre-render the pages into .cs files (I have some old code for that). But like I said: it doesn't really add value IMHO.

Comment: @JHBonarius not sure how it works, but I meant about partially compiling part of the content. So after compiling it, that partial part should be represented by ***something***. For example, if you precompile the whole view file, usually it can be a `dll` representing that view file.

Comment: @KingKing the Razor engine renderer will convert the .cshtml file to a .generated.cs file, full of things like `WriteLiteral(" class=\"btn btn-primary-nw btn-sm js-filter\"");`, `witeAttribute(...)`, normal C# code, etc (really big files). That will all be compiled into the dll when doing a normal build.

Comment: @JHBonarius that's not precompiling. Precompiling should be resulted in some `dll`. You have options to precompile the view files or keep the view files and run them on the fly. As long as the code is plain text, it's not precompiled. If you think that's called ***partial*** precompiling, so the remaining content ***is still not precompiled***, right? Again, please focus on the term ***partial precompiling***. It's not the right term explained by what you described. Although that hacking way may work for the OP's purpose.

Comment: @KingKing I don't understand you. like I say: you generate cshtml into cs, **_which get compiled into a dll on build_**. Do you suggest a dll for every view file? That would be in the thousands for any big project! Any time gained by prerendering would be lost by loading time of all these files...

Comment: @JHBonarius I don't suggest anything, I meant that when we call it compiling or precompiling, the result file is usually not plain text (like `.cs`, `.cshtml`). Actually you can have all the view files precompiled into dll files. It should be the fastest option to run the pages but it has a trade-off of not being able to modify the view files easily at runtime (you usually need to replace the whole dll file).